# List comprehensions -require base case?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I don't understand why the base case is needed in this:

```
-- perms :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
perms [] = [[]]
perms xs = [ (x:ps) | x <- xs, ps <- perms (xs \\ [x])]
```

It seems to me that it should be automatic from the list-comprehension, but then I noticed that:

```
[ x:y | x<-[], y<-[] ]
```

evaluates to [], and not [[]], which seems surprising.

Even so, I was also surprised that without the base case it runs, but always gives [], which violates the type signature.
Is there an easy way to trace the execution of a list comprehension? It seems atomic to Debug.Trace.trace.

Comment: The return value `[]` does not violate the type signature. An empty array is still a `[[a]]`.

Comment: And also, why was the base case needed - seems like the LC should handle the whole thing. And, any easy way to see a trace of the LC expansion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's de-sugar!

```
[ x:y | x <- [], y <- [] ]
```

Turns into

```
do x <- []
   y <- []
   return (x:y)
```

Now, more de-sugaring! Yay!

```
[] >>= \x -> ([] >>= \y -> return (x:y))
```

iirc, `>>=` for lists is `flip concatMap`, and `return` is simply `\x -> [x]`

Let's only do a little bit of that replacement.

```
concatMap (\x -> ([] >>= \y -> return (x:y))) []
```

There, now do you see? `concatMap f []` will obviously evaluate to `[]`. Because `concatMap f` is just `concat . map f`. So map `f` onto the empty list, and then concatenate the results. Except there are no results, so the final evaluation is `[]`.

Comment: If you'd like references or don't understand the de-sugaring, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks. Good approach. I'll have to stare at it a bit more! I had it up to the (x=[],y=[], return ([]:[]) - but that means return ([[]]). It was the concatMap step that I was missing.

Comment: @guthrie Coming from a C or Java background, where `return` means "exit the function with this value", will do that to you sometimes. Always remember that Haskell's `return` is completely different.

Answer (score 8):

You can think of `<-` as use every element from the list in right in the expression in left.
Since `[]` has no elements the whole list comprehension returns an empty list.
It will be strange if `[ x:y | x<-[], y<-[] ]` returns `[[]]` because `:` takes element and a list. So to generate `[[]]` y must be `[]` but then what will be `x`?

As KennyTM said `[]` is of type `[[a]]`. Actually `[]` is from every type of this kind:
`[a] [[a]] [[[a]]]` and so on. If it wasn't then there is no way a function to return an empty list.

Anyway it is a very common mistake to forget some brackets and this is why type annotations are necessary.

Comment: I thought (incorrectly!), xs=[], so x=[], and []\\[] = [], and then []:[] => [[]]. asking Gchi :type of [] and of [[]] it does show them differently, but I suppose one subsumes the other.

Comment: @guthrie: You suppose correctly. The type of `[]` is `[a]` for any type `a`, including types such as `[b]`.

Comment: @guthrie: You might enjoy comparing the output of `:t []` to the output of `:t [] :: [[a]]` in ghci. The former gives what's known as the _principle type_ of `[]` -- that is, the most general type. It is most general in the sense that it can be specialized by substituting any other type consistently for any type variable and still give a valid typing.

Answer (score 3):

So it comes down to the meaning of

```
[ x:y | x<-[], y<-[] ]
```

The way to read this is, "What are the possible values of `x:y`, when `x` has no possible values, and `y` has no possible values?"  Hopefully, it should be clear that in that case, there are no values at all for `x:y`, since you'd need a value for `x` and a value for `y` to get a possibility for `x:y`, and you have neither.

This general pattern of selecting combinations of possible values for `x` and `y` is called a *cartesian product*, and the word "product" is used in part because the number of possibile combinations is equal to the number of possibilities for `x`, *times* the number of possibilities for `y`.  So if there are zero choices for `x`, and zero choices for `y`, you can expect `0 * 0 = 0` choices for combinations of the two.

Comment: I guess the "secret" is that if the first source is exhausted, no further elements are generated for others in the chain, so nothing is returned - i.e. []. If there were zero choices for x, then the generator chain stopped there - y generation was never attempted(?). I of course get the overall logic of the generators, but not the details of this type of thing, does it stop once any one of the variables is exhausted - seems logical, and seems yes?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another hint why there is a base case with an empty list.  How many permutations are there of `n` elements?  There are `n!` permutations.  And what is `0!`?  It's 1.  So the length of the result list for `perm []` has to be 1.  The types and the lack of elements of type `a` forces the result to be `[[]]`.  No other defined value has the right type and length.

Comment: Yes, thanks - I know the theory and basic idea, just not yet familiar with the Haskell implementations of LC.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list comprehension of the form:

```
[ x:y | stuff ]
```

then you are producing a list whose elements are of the form `x:y` for some choices of `x` and `y` as determined by `stuff`. `[[]]` is a list whose elements are not of the form `x:y` for any `x` or `y`, so the former cannot produce the latter.

In expecting `[[]]` from `[ x:y | x <- [], y <- [] ]`, you seem to be setting `x = []` and `y = []` and then considering `x:y = [[]]`. This is wrong for a couple of reasons:

- `x` is coming from `xs` of type `[a]`, so `x` has type `a`, and is not (in general) a list
- the result of the list comprehension is a *list* of `x:y` elements, not a single one.